# Postfix as smart host for Exchange 2016

Tags: postfix, exchange

I am trying to set up `Postfix` as a smart host for an Exchange 2016 server. Right now I have it successfully relaying mail in to Exchange from the internet but outbound relay is not working.

I'm looking to get the simplest setup to essentially make this box be a mail proxy for Exchange 2016.

- `mx1.example.com` == Exchange server (A Record)
- `mailfw01.example.com` == this postfix server (A record)
- `example.com. MX mailfw01.example.com.` (MX Record)

Inbound Mail Flow (works in the current config):

- AnyDomain -> `mailfw01.example.com:25` -> `mx1.example.com:50510`
- (Sender)  -> (In to postfix on port 25) -> (In to Exchange on port 50510)

Outbound Mail (does not work):

- Exchange -> Postfix -> Any Remote Domain
- Exchange outbound connector as smarthost to Postfix -> Postfix(?) -> recipient

Below is the postfix configuration I have:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no   
readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
myhostname = mailfw01.example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mailfw01.example.com, mailfw1.example.com, example.com, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = mx1.example.com:50510
mynetworks = 0.0.0.0/0
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

#added lines
mydomain = example.com
relay_domains = $mydestination
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,\
        reject_unauth_destination,reject_invalid_hostname,\
        reject_unauth_pipelining,reject_non_fqdn_sender, \
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,reject_unknown_sender_domain
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
relay_recipient_maps =
local_recipient_maps =
compatibility_level = 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are sending outbound mail back to Exchange:

```
relayhost = mx1.example.com:50510
```

Empty your `relayhost`, as the indound mail may use [`transport_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#transport_maps) to find the correct nexthop destination.

Another problem with you current configuration is that you now accept mail for `*@example.com` and don't use *connection-stage rejection* for non-existing mailboxes, as direct delivery to Exchange would do. This may lead to sending backscatter *Non-Delivery Notifications*.

Postfix needs to be aware of existing mailboxes. This can be achieved using [`relay_recipient_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#relay_recipient_maps), but you need to maintain it manually. This is, however, consistent with the standard configuration example for [Postfix email firewall/gateway](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#firewall).